# Send stdout and stderr to file, syslog, and terminal

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

For some cloud machines I'm launching, I'm trying to log to a specific file, syslog, and the terminal/console.

At the top of my machine setup/cloud-init scripts, I have the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec &> >(tee "/tmp/box-setup.log" | logger -t box-setup)
apt-get install -y some-package
```

This works great at sending output to a file and syslog, but it doesn't pipe to the output to the terminal.

Generally speaking not having terminal output isn't a huge problem except when I'm debugging from a remote console. When that happens, I'm completely blind because the console is blank as the bash script executes.

Is there a simple way using `bash` redirection or whatever to pipe all output (standard output along with standard error) to a file, syslog, and the terminal simultaneously?

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add a nested process substitution and another `tee` in there like:

```
exec &> >(tee >(tee "/tmp/box-setup.log" | logger -t box-setup))
```

The first `tee` within the main process substitution sends STDOUT/STDERR to terminal and also to the nested process substitution, the `tee` inside that saves the content in file `/tmp/box-setup.log` and the pipe is used to send the output to `logger`'s STDIN too.

Comment: i'm confused about multiple tee invocations, it will fork to n streams, shouldn't this be equivalent?
`exec &> >(tee /tmp/box-setup.log >(logger -t box-setup))`

Answer (score 3):

> I'm completely blind because the console is blank as the bash script executes.

You might want to solve that problem a different way: run your bash script in the background, and run `less /tmp/box-setup.log` and hit F to keep updating the screen as lines are added to the file it's watching (like `tail -f`).

If running the script in the background is a problem, use `tmux` or `screen` to get multiple sessions multiplexed onto one ssh connection.  Use the same `less` command in another shell.

---

The original problem:

`tee` can copy to multiple destinations.  Make one of them the terminal, using the `/dev/tty` special file.  I think it always refers to the controlling tty of the current process.  Or probably better, to `/dev/stderr`, since `tee`'s stderr is still connected to the shell's stderr.  (This lets you silence the script with &> /dev/null).

```
exec &> >(tee /dev/stderr "/tmp/box-setup.log" | logger -t box-setup)
```

BTW, this is equivalent to but more efficient than `(tee /dev/stderr | tee "/tmp/box-setup.log" | logger ...)`.

It would be possible to use some file-descriptor cloning to give `tee` the original script's stdout, rather than stderr.

Answer (score 2):

Simply add `/dev/stderr` (your choice) as an output to `tee`.

```
exec &> >(tee /dev/stderr "/tmp/box-setup.log" | logger -t box-setup)
```

Standard output and standard error will be merged. There's no way to keep them separate if you want to preserve their order, which is usually desirable. It doesn't matter if they're both going to the same place (e.g. the terminal) anyway.

Comment: `tee`'s stdout is the pipe to logger, not the terminal.  It's `stderr` at that point is still the terminal, based on `exec &> >(tee /dev/stderr > /dev/null)` working as expected in an interactive shell.  `stderr` seems like a better idea than my `/dev/tty` idea, since it lets you easily shut the script up with a redirect if you want.